# Output extend for raster calculator (setnull set)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, iteration

We are working on a project to find least cost path for marine shipping based on some criteria. In a phase when iterating raster datasets and using raster calculation to use setnull function to exclude some criteria in a final raster. Problem with the output is that the extend is based on a smaller raster (one dataset is for the whole world and the second one just for arctic regions which the output is clipped). We want the output to appear on a worldwide scale.
I have tried to change everything in geoprocessing environments but still getting output just for the area from a smaller raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that's happening, and I'm no expert at arcgis or using distance tools, but came across this on the cost path page on ArcGIS:

> Cost Path will ignore the Cell size environment setting and use the cell size of the Input cost backlink raster for the output raster. The pattern of the   back link raster would be seriously altered if it were resampled to a different resolution. To avoid any confusion, the cell size should not be set > when using this tool.

Perhaps you need to check if this applies to the extent as well? Perhaps all rasters need to use the same extent, or at least the backlink does...?